# optimal configuration for basic lan- home router and two switches

Tags: networking, router, switch

please bear with me as i'm a novice at best.

so there are about 60-70 network devices in this small office network- computers, printers etc.

so we have a modem- provided by our isp with a 300mbps/300mbps service- connected to a netgear router. the router is in turn connected to a cisco gs200 50-port switch. the need arose for more wired devices, so we got another gs200 switch.

i've paired the switches as pictured:
[image]

everything seems to work fine, just uncertain if this is adequate for the network, or if an alternate configuration, such as pairing each switch directly with the router would provide practical benefits.

Comment: "_please bare with me,,,_" Are you asking us to get naked with you? I don't know you that well. :) I think you mean, "_please bear with me_," as in bearing (direction). I often see this mistake, and the phrase, "_baited breath_", and I ask if they had sushi for lunch, or did they mean, "_bated breath_?"

Comment: In case you might be interested to ask in [Hardware Recommendations site](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @RonMaupin - oops! god catch. usually one to note the difference.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure what the NetGear device's specs are, I suspect that the two Cisco-200-50s will have an easier time passing intra-LAN traffic between them, rather than have the NetGear device broker the packet switching between each switch.  As you have it, the NetGear will only have to deal with up to the 300 Mb/s internet connection, and it will only have to send that traffic to one of its ports.

You might want to look into something like the old-school [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/mrtg.en.html%20MRTG) application to help manage bandwidth utilization on your switches.